# epub.js set font size

Tags: javascript, epub.js

I'm using epub.js to render .epub books, but I cant set fonSize in some ebooks, it wont override existing classes with the font-size already set on the ebook;

I read the [documentation](http://epubjs.org/documentation/0.3/#themes) and the [issues](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/issues).

Here is the [source](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/epubjs/dist/epub.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to set the fontsize with this but neither works in a epub that have font-size already set :

`rendition = book.renderTo("viewer", { width: "100%", height: "100%" });
rendition.themes.fontSize("200%"); //this dont work
rendition.themes.default({ "body": { "font-size": "30px"}}); //this dont work`

The solution is to loop each child class and reset to desired size.
I dont know how to do this.

Can anyone point me to the right diretion?
How can I set the font size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved with:

```
 rendition.themes.default({ "p": { "font-size": "medium !important"}})
```